# Netbeans Generics Bug using FEST, Java?

Tags: java, generics, netbeans, fest

I have the following non-generic method for getting a JListFixture using FEST:

```
public static JListFixture getJListFixtureNonGeneric(final FrameFixture frame) {
    return frame.list(new GenericTypeMatcher<MyClass>(MyClass.class) {
        @Override
        protected boolean isMatching(MyClass component) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I have the following generic method for getting a JListFixture using FEST:

```
public static <T extends Component> JListFixture getJListFixture(final FrameFixture frame, final Class<T> t) {
    return frame.list(new GenericTypeMatcher<T>(t) {
        @Override
        protected boolean isMatching(T component) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

In Netbeans 7.3, the non-generic method compiles without error.  The generic method however does not.  The editor window does not show any compilation errors (No red lines at any line numbers). However, if I try to compile it by right-clicking on the project and clicking 'Test', I get the following error:

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_21). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
>
> ```
> java.lang.AssertionError: Missing type variable in where clause T
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.util.RichDiagnosticFormatter.unique(RichDiagnosticFormatter.java:234)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.util.RichDiagnosticFormatter.access$100(RichDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.util.RichDiagnosticFormatter$RichPrinter.visitTypeVar(RichDiagnosticFormatter.java:384)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.util.RichDiagnosticFormatter$RichPrinter.visitTypeVar(RichDiagnosticFormatter.java:326)
> ...
> C:\myProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1248: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\myProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> ```

Line 1248 in the stacktrace corresponds to the j2seproject3 element below:

```xml
<target depends="init,deps-jar,compile,-pre-pre-compile-test,-pre-compile-test,-compile-test-depend" if="have.tests" name="-do-compile-test">
    <j2seproject3:javac apgeneratedsrcdir="${build.test.classes.dir}" classpath="${javac.test.classpath}" debug="true" destdir="${build.test.classes.dir}" processorpath="${javac.test.processorpath}" srcdir="${test.test.dir}"/>
    <copy todir="${build.test.classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${test.test.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Line 268 in the stacktrace points to the following below:

```xml
<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

...

Has anyone encountered this or know what to do to make it work? Is this, in fact a true bug?